# Индивидуальная БД

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Пытаюсь разработать приложение, в нем есть БД, которая является уникальной у каждого пользователя (они добавляют строки сами). Также используется Firebase для аутентификации пользователей (по email). 
"Прошерстив" гугл я так поняла, что Realtime Database используется для одной общей базы данных для всех пользователей.
Так вот вопрос, как можно сделать, чтобы у каждого пользователя была своя бд ?)

Comment: У каждого пользователя, который зарегистрирован и залогинен есть свой уникальный номер. Вот по этому номеру в базе данных вам и надо создавать папку в бд, к которой и должен будет обращаться пользователь при запросе. Также следует защитить папки правилами, чтобы у пользователей не было доступа к чужим папкам.

Comment: @Mr.Krotos а что лучше использовать Cloud Firestore или Realtime Database?

Comment: Это в зависимости от вашего проекта и смотря что вам будет удобней. Лично мне удобней Cloud Firestore